# Bootstrap glyphicons in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

How can i make bootstrap glyphicons work with the database? I mean for example, I wanted to use check mark and the x-mark glyphicons to correspond it with the database data, in the database it has boolean 1 and 0. So if its 1 the corresponding icon should be the check mark if 0 it should be the x-mark:

This is my php code, It used to be yes and no, now my client wants it to be check mark and x-mark

```
<td> <?php echo $row->hscard== true ? 'yes':'no';?> <br></td>
<td> <?php echo $row->tor== true ? 'yes':'no';?><br></td>
<td> <?php echo $row->dismissal== true ? 'yes':'no';?><br></td>
<td> <?php echo $row->goodmoral== true ? 'yes':'no';?><br></td>
<td> <?php echo $row->bcrtfcate== true ? 'yes':'no';?><br></td>
<td> <?php echo $row->form137== true ? 'yes':'no';?>  <br></td>
<td> <?php echo $row->grade_evaluation == true ? 'yes':'no';?><br></td>
```

Comment: According to the other answeres I would only pass the changing parameter `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-<?php echo $row->hscard   == true ? 'ok':'remove';?>"></i>` guess it looks and feels better coding like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td> <i class="glyphicon <?php echo $row->hscard   == true ? 'glyphicon-ok':'glyphicon-remove';?>"></i> <br></td>
<td> <i class="glyphicon <?php echo $row->tor      == true ? 'glyphicon-ok':'glyphicon-remove';?>"></i> <br></td>
<td> <i class="glyphicon <?php echo $row->dismissal== true ? 'glyphicon-ok':'glyphicon-remove';?>"></i> <br></td>
<td> <i class="glyphicon <?php echo $row->goodmoral== true ? 'glyphicon-ok':'glyphicon-remove';?>"></i> <br></td>
<td> <i class="glyphicon <?php echo $row->bcrtfcate== true ? 'glyphicon-ok':'glyphicon-remove';?>"></i> <br></td>
<td> <i class="glyphicon <?php echo $row->form137  == true ? 'glyphicon-ok':'glyphicon-remove';?>"></i>  <br></td>
<td> <i class="glyphicon <?php echo $row->grade_evaluation == true ? 'glyphicon-ok':'glyphicon-remove';?>"></i> <br></td>
```

try with this

Answer (score 1):

You should do it exactly as in the code you shared.
first of all, don't forget to include bootstrap css file in your html.

```
<td>
    <span class="glyphicon 
      <?php echo $row->grade_evaluation == true ? 'glyphicon-ok':'glyphicon-remove';?> ">
    </span>
</td>
```